How to start consuming messages from specific offset using Confluent Kafka Python consumer
Using the Confluent Kafka Python consumer, how do I start consuming from a specific offset? At first I was going use the seek() method, but documentation makes it seem like you can not start reading from a specific offset.

seek() may only be used to update the consume offset of an actively
consumed partition (i.e., after assign()), to set the starting offset
of partition not being consumed instead pass the offset in an assign()
call.

Simple example:
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, TopicPartition

consumer = Consumer({...})
consumer.subscribe(['topic-test'])
tp = TopicPartition('topic-test', 0, 10)
consumer.seek(tp)

Running this code throws the exception:
cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError {
   code=_UNKNOWN_PARTITION,
   val=-190,
   str="Failed to seek to offset 10: Local: Unknown partition"
}


What's the issue with what you've shown?

Updated to show the exception the code throws

To solve this problem, you can try using: assign
try:
    # Assign the specific partition with the desired offset
    tp = TopicPartition(topic, partition, offset)
    consumer.assign([tp])

